# Show New List Item Form depending on user

Tags: 2010, list, form

Is it possible in Sharepoint 2010 to show different forms for a list item depending on the user and his permissions but without Infopath?

Because I need a task list for a department where people in this department should have more options when they create a task than people which are not in that department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use site columns and content types.  You can set permissions on them.  Some people will get some fields in the form, others get different fields in the same form.  All out-of-the-box, without SPD, InfoPath, Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Content Editor Webpart and add links to each of the forms. Then use audience targeting to show/hide the different form url's.

Another option is to use SharePoint JavaScript Object Model to check the permission and show/hide form elements. This approach does not provide fool proof security

Another option is to create custom webpart and then use that to display the form and then use the server side code to hide UI elements.

Comment: For option 1 I would need different forms to do that. How could I get them? But would be the easiest way.

Comment: You can use SharePoint Designer to create new forms. Just check in google.